# Filter by exact substring in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, mysql-workbench

Let's say I have this table with a column named `groups`:

| groups |
| --- |
| X0C5TB24 |
| X11C17N24 |
| X1C14B25 |
| X7C18B15 |
| X0C88TB12 |
| ... |

I want to use `WHERE` to filter values which give me exactly `"X0"` or `"X1"` so my final result should be:

| groups |
| --- |
| X0C5TB24 |
| X1C14B25 |
| X0C88TB12 |

My attempts so far:

```
WHERE
    groups REGEXP "^X[0-1]"
```

and

```
WHERE
    SUBSTR(groups, 1,2) IN ("X0","X1")
```

But these also returns `"X11C17N24"` which is not what I want since it's actually `X11` and not `X0` or `X1` (the `C` in value acts as the delimiter).

I can't find a solution or something close to my problem neither here nor somewhere else so any advice or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try: `REGEXP '^X[0-1][a-zA-Z]'`.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return that? It begins with `X1`, which is what you said you want to match.

Comment: @Barmar , I think `C` is the delimiter for those Xs .. since `"X11C17N24"` is actually `X11`, it wasn't suppose to return the value.

Comment: Btw, MySQL workbench 8.0 does not represent MySQL version. Run `SELECT version();` to check exact MySQL version.

Comment: @FanoFN You're probably right, but the OP should confirm it before you edit it into the question.

Comment: Ya... I guess that's true, OP should confirm it first before I edit.. I'm too confident that's the case .. should I rollback?

Answer (score 0):

If C is always going to be your delimiter, you can simply add it to your expression. Example:

```
WHERE groups REGEXP "^X[01][C]"
```

produces the following output:

```
groups
X0C5TB24
X0C88TB12
X1C14B25
```

If the character could be any letter, but not a number, use this to get the same result:

```
WHERE groups REGEXP "^X[01][a-zA-Z.]"
```

Comment: Trivia:  `[01]` works just as well as `[0-1]`.

Comment: @RickJames [Correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9073c1/2) Your comment is helpful

Comment: [0-9] is the same as [0123456789], but it is not the same as [09] which only returns 0 and 9. The dash is used to indicate all numbers between the starting number and the ending number. Obviously, it is not necessary for [01] which does not contain any numbers between.